# Knockout foreach binding - 2 on a row

Tags: css

```
<div data-bind='foreach:images'>            
<figure>
<img data-bind='attr:{src:src}' ></img>
<figcaption data-bind='text:name' contenteditable='true' ></figcaption>                
</figure>             
</div>
```

What this does is displays images vertically - since figure ( an fig caption are block elements).

What I am trying to achieve is this

1 2
3 4
5 6
..
..

i.e 2 images in each row. 
I've tried a no. of things but could not some up with anything. Do I need to use  knockout templates ?

Comment: Are the images all the same size?

Comment: I have set the max-width and max-height to 100px

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Untested, but with the help of some CSS, you should be able to achieve it by using the `index` observable Knockout exposes within loops to get the current index:

CSS:

```
.container { overflow: hidden; }
.l { float: left; }
.clear { clear: left; }
```

Markup:

```
<div data-bind='foreach: images' class='container'>
  <figure class='l'>
    <img data-bind='attr: {src:src}'></img>
    <figcaption data-bind='text: name' contenteditable='true'></figcaption>
  </figure>
  <!-- ko if: ($index() + 1) % 2 === 0 -->
  <div class='clear'></div>
  <!-- /ko -->
</div>
```

If your images are of a standard width then you could achieve the wrapping without the clear `div` by floating the `figure` tags as above, and setting the width of the container `div` to twice the image width.

I've created a JSFiddle showing the first method [here](http://jsfiddle.net/jmnhg3n3/).

Comment: Well it did not change anything

Comment: I am doing this in a chrome extension that displays all the images on a web page vertically

Comment: I've updated my answer and added a link to a JSFiddle to show it working :)

Comment: agreed that this should solve your issue, unless you're leaving some details out.  You should post a fiddle of your attempt and how it's breaking otherwise.  Also - you should tag this question CSS and remove knockout - as it has nothing to do with knockout.

Comment: Hey Steve it worked. So effectively your solution is a very logical CSS thing, right ? Keep floating to the left ( and not on another line ) . It moves to another line when it does not find enough space for the next image, and there the story begins again.I think we were moving to the next line because img is a block element - figure behaves 'inline' by default

Comment: That's basically it, yeah - the KO part of the solution is the `if` binding, but when I originally had that in the div's data-bind attribute instead of in the KO comment binding the div was rendered every time, putting a `clear` after every image. Happy to help, though! :)